# Define different styles for typography with SketchApp

Tags: typography, sketch-app, css

How can I define styles for typography with SketchApp?
For example, I have a H4 with these variants:

- Normal
- Bold
- Colorful

I defined as:

[image: styleguide]

It seems very unorganized and helps the developer to define the style in the CSS.

I can't assign different styles to an element with SketchApp as HTML.
I would avoid assigning individual styles for each element and create a Styleguide instead.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to organize your styles in "folders" or groups. If you name a style "h4/BodyBold/color" and another "h4/BodyBold/Default", they will behave as nested folders, making it much easier to select and understand:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases here:

1. You can make a style of text.
2. [You can make a text symbol.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73352/update-text-content-on-multiple-artboards-at-once-in-sketch/79980#79980)

First case (creating style) is defined below. For second case follow the link.

**Write a text and make it bold, color it and add all the stylings you require.**

[image: Write a text and make it bold, color it and add all the stylings you require.]

**Just above the Typeface(Font Name of text) No text style is written select create a new text style and name it.**
[image: Just above the Typeface(Font selection) No text style is written select create a new text style and name it.]

**Write another text with different or default text attributes and select style from the same place.**
[image: Write another text with different or default text attributes and select style from the same place.]

**You can see it'll pick all the attributes of that specific text style.**
[image: You can see it'll pick all the attributes of that specific text style.]

**NOTE:** If you change one text i.e. unbold it it'll not effect the other one. In order to change attributes of one heading and it'll change them everywhere in the document you need to [create a symbol of text.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73352/update-text-content-on-multiple-artboards-at-once-in-sketch/79980#79980)