# Update Text Content on Multiple Artboards at Once in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, automation

I need to generate a number of banner ads each week and currently use Sketch for doing so.  In order to save time, I'm trying to automate (or at least improve the process flow) for this as much as possible.  One of the things that needs to be done is to update both the special offer details and the offer code that needs to be used in ever banner size.

So what I'm looking for is a way to update the text in these 10 different text fields (one for each banner size) without having to manually select each one and type in the new text.  Bonus points if the same (or similar) method will allow me to swap images on each of the 10 artboards too!

I've already looked through the Sketch Plugin Directory but haven't found anything I think will really do it.

Comment: I also have this use case, for making marketing materials for the App Store. I have to have the same text for 4 different screen sizes. Sketch has "data" now but that's for random text not specific text ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by creating symbols of text and image. In this case you'll just need to change one and all the others will be changed.
**Create an artboard and insert text.**
[image: Create an artboard with a text]

**With text selected goto layer > create symbol**
[image: goto layer in menu and create symbol]

**Give you symbol a name i.e. Banner Main Heading**
[image: name your symbol]

**make a copy of the artboard**
[image: make a copy of artboard]

**double click any Text and it'll open up another page of symbol. Change the text here to hello**
[image: double click on text and change text]

**This is how symbol works. Whereever you copy this symbol in the same project will not matter. If you change it at one place it'll be changed at all places**
 
[image: see the changed result]

You can do the same for images and symbols that you make. Like if you have made an icon a symbol and you change it's color it'll be change at all places. While working with symbols you need to be careful though.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution. It gets painful when managing text as symbols in a design system except maybe when used as input placeholders or buttons